# OneDrive API Throttling

Tags: onedrive

From the API documentation page,

> OneDrive has limits in place to make sure that individuals and apps do not adversely affect the experience of other users. When an activity exceeds OneDrive's limits, API requests will be rejected for a period of time. OneDrive may also return a Retry-After header with the number of seconds your app should wait before sending more requests.

I have seen developers from Microsoft commenting that [not revealing the throttling limit is intentional](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c4aaa90c-dc75-441f-9b30-f5c45e402ac4/limitation-on-api-requestfile-size-limitationresume-upload?forum=onedriveapi).

Is there any way to increase the throttling limit? Does OneDrive provide a paid service?

Comment: Have you hit a throttle limit and are concerned about your application?

Comment: We have not hit a limit yet but we are concerned since our application is for enterprise users. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OneDrive does not provide a way to increase throttle limits and there is no paid application program at this time.

The limits that the OneDrive service allows for applications to be created that use its APIs for uploading and downloading data consistent with a sync client.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So the only way we can determine the limit is by a DoS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OneDrive provide a paid service, but I believe Microsoft is pretty lenient with this limit. As long as your traffic doesn't suddenly become unexpectedly high, generally you won't get throttled.

But since you said your program is for enterprise users, simply gradually increasing the traffic request to let OneDrive "learn" your request habit will help.